# How to specify which nodes in the feature map get applied with different filters/layers in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

For example, say I wanted to apply a 1D Convolution to FFT data and Raw time series data in the first layer (suppose the first 400 nodes, as an example), but use a simple feed forward network to some 1D Statistical features on the remaining, say 20 nodes. Then combine those outputs in the next layer.

I'm mostly used to just adding a layer which is able to interact with any node in the previous layer, which is why I'm confused here. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

edit:

One thing I forgot to add to the answer above, segments of the feature vector can be selected by taking a `tf.slice` of the input data, or by using similar slicing notation as you would in numpy arrays i.e `Data = Input(shape...) first_10 = Data[:10]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems easiest with [the functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional). You should be able to do something like

```
def model(input_shape):
    Data = Input(shape=input_shape, name="Input")
    ConvOutput = Conv1D()(Data)
    SimpleFeatures = Dense()(Data)

    Combined = tf.concat()([ConvOutput, SimpleFeatures])

    return Model(inputs=Data, outputs=Combined)
```

to control the input/output of specific layers, as well as combining the results of multiple different nodes.